# Weird shaking with hinge joint in Scene Kit

Tags: ios, scenekit

i'm trying to make a join, tank with turret, but because of this joint whole model is shaking, do you have any ideas what causing this behaviour?

Link to project: [Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57X9-CqpCMCNVdvemthZUhfUW8/edit?usp=sharing)

this is how i made it:

```
    SCNNode *tankNode = [extraScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Main_Body" recursively:YES];
[tankNode setScale:SCNVector3Make(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)];
[tankNode setPosition:SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0)];
[tankNode setPhysicsBody:[SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody]];
[tankNode setRotation:SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, -M_PI_2)];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:tankNode];

SCNNode *turretNode = [tankNode childNodeWithName:@"Turret" recursively:YES];
turretNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
SCNNode *gunNode = [turretNode childNodeWithName:@"gun" recursively:YES];
gunNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];

SCNPhysicsHingeJoint *gunJoint = [SCNPhysicsHingeJoint jointWithBodyA:turretNode.physicsBody axisA:SCNVector3Make(0,0,1) anchorA:SCNVector3Make(0.1,0.1,0.1) bodyB:gunNode.physicsBody axisB:SCNVector3Make(0,0,1) anchorB:SCNVector3Make(0.1,0.1,0.1)];

[scene.physicsWorld addBehavior:gunJoint];

SCNPhysicsHingeJoint *turretJoint = [SCNPhysicsHingeJoint jointWithBodyA:turretNode.physicsBody axisA:SCNVector3Make(0,1,0) anchorA:SCNVector3Make(0.1,0.1,0.1) bodyB:tankNode.physicsBody axisB:SCNVector3Make(0,1,0) anchorB:SCNVector3Make(0.5,0.5,-0.1)];

[scene.physicsWorld addBehavior:turretJoint];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems:

- you are are assigning a constraint between a node and one of its child node (turret and tank). This is unlikely to give the expected results since a child node position is relative to its parent (so let's say the constraint moves the parent node, it will also move the child node).
- you are assigning a constraint between two static bodies (gun & turret) - this should have no effect

Comment: When I change first thing then whole model just fly away somewhere(i tried to set collisionBitMask to 0 and dynamic/static and kinematic body. and when i leave turretNode as a child od tank and set turret body to dynamic, the turret just fall down inside the tankNode

Answer (score 0):

Im only guessing here but i'd imagine you are placing a joint inside tankNode's physics body due to the fact you have scaled the tankNode, but not its physics shape.

Remember scaling a SCNNode does not scale its physics shape.
If you need your tank to be scaled : ensure you scale the physics body as well -
`SCNVector3 Scale=SCNVector3Make(0.003, 0.003, 0.003);`

Then your physics shape should be scaled :

```
NSDictionary *options=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3:Scale] forKey:SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey];
```

Now create a physics body from the scaled shape :

```
SCNPhysicsShape *physicsGeometry=[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:tankNode.geometry options:options];
```

Finally add the physics shape to your tank

```
tankNode.physicsBody=[SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:physicsGeometry];
```

Your physics body and Tank node are now the same size.

If you require physics on the cannon and turret,  i.e. the cannon needs to collide, create its physics body the same way..

Your code would suggest that turret and gun are children of the tank. The best / easiest way is to parent the turret to the gun so the gun is a child of the turret, and then parent the turret to the tank. This way, moving the tank moves the gun, turret and tank, Moving the turret moves the turret and the gun, and moving the gun only moves the gun.
Also in your 3d authoring software don't forget to move the pivot to the required centre of rotation for each node (or set it using SCNNode.pivot property).

You won't even need to use joints at all in this circumstance if the parent / child hierarchy is correct :)

I hope this helps.